# How to send the data from one page to another page? using ionic and angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

The project has a tab section in that i have two pages
1. recipe page
2. favorite

in recipe page their is a list of recipes and i added a add icon button at the end of each list.
How to send list from the recipe page to favorite page by clicking the add icon button.

pls help me

Ionic, angular

Comment: you can create the list in the parent page, and pass the ref of that list to both tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that i know.

1. Using Services. (I prefer this one)

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class dataService {
    data: string;

    setData(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    getData(){
       return this.data;
    }
}
```

App.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { dataService } from './server.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private dataService: dataService){}

  getData() {
      retrun this.dataService.getData();
  }

}
```

2) Using the NavController

```
this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {
      data: userData
});
```

On homepage you can access the passed data like this

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.userData = navParams.get('data');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an option from one page to another, this is a good way.

First, you have to list the options and when choosing one, you push to another page

In index.html:

```
<ion-card *ngFor= "let elemento of resultado.list;  let i = index"></ion-card>
```

recipes.js:

```
this.navCtrl.push( FavoritePage,{op: i} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The most use solution on that type of case is to call services. You call a service to store the data that you want, and then call it on the other page. If you have any doubts on how to do it and never done a service, feel free to ask.